# Wordpress PHP code: Show only modified date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have got a Wordpress blog and I need to show only the modified date and not the published one.

Now It writes on the post: Published at: 28 May 2018 - Updated: 21 Apr 2020

The difference is too big and and in this case I would only to show the Updated date.

I got this code right now:

```
      <?php if( get_the_modified_date() != get_the_date() || get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() ) : ?>

          <?php
            $modified_date = get_the_modified_date( get_option('date_format') );
            $machine_readable_modified_date = esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) );
          ?>
          <?php _e('Published', 'hueman'); ?> <time class="published" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_published_date; ?>"><?php echo $published_date; ?></time>
          &middot; <?php _e('Updated', 'hueman'); ?> <time class="updated" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_modified_date; ?>"><?php echo $modified_date; ?></time>
      <?php else : ?>
          <time class="published" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_published_date; ?>"><?php echo $published_date; ?></time>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I fix it? Its probably easy but I know **zero** PHP code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all information about published date

```
          <?php if( get_the_modified_date() != get_the_date() || get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() ) : ?>
          <?php
            $modified_date = get_the_modified_date( get_option('date_format') );
            $machine_readable_modified_date = esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) );
          ?>
          <?php _e('Updated', 'hueman'); ?> <time class="updated" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_modified_date; ?>"><?php echo $modified_date; ?></time>
      <?php else : ?>
          <time class="published" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_published_date; ?>"><?php echo $published_date; ?></time>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about it. Would it affect if the post has only a published date? And not an updated one?

Comment: Np, when you create a post then the update date will be the same as the post date

Answer (score 0):

Im not clearly understand your question.if you want to show only modification date then this might will help you.

simply remove the tag  that have class publish

```
   <?php if( get_the_modified_date() != get_the_date() || get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time() ) : ?>

          <?php
            $modified_date = get_the_modified_date( get_option('date_format') );
            $machine_readable_modified_date = esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) );
          ?>
          <?php _e('Published', 'hueman'); ?> 
          &middot; <?php _e('Updated', 'hueman'); ?> <time class="updated" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_modified_date; ?>"><?php echo $modified_date; ?></time>
      <?php else : ?>
          <time class="published" datetime="<?php echo $machine_readable_published_date; ?>"><?php echo $published_date; ?></time>
      <?php endif; ?>
```